# Fixed point for a function that is "opposite of a contraction".

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider a complete metric space $(M,d)$ and a function $f:M\rightarrow M$ surjective and such that $d(f(x),f(y))\geq Kd(x,y)$, for some $K>1$ and $\forall x,y \in M$. Show that  $\exists! x \in M$ such that $f(x) = x$.

I know there is some results involving compactness, but I'm not allowed to use those.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What about $M=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x \geq 1\}$ and $f(x) = K\cdot x$?

Comment: Sorry... I forgot to mention that $f$ must be surjective!

Comment: in that case $f$ has an inverse and that inverse is a contraction.

Comment: You're right! Easy one... Thank you very much!

Comment: @WimC You could turn that into an answer.

Comment: A complete metric space need not be compact. Recall that a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete *and* totally bounded.

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT: while I was typing this, WimC gave basically the same observation in a comment. If they turn their comment into an answer I'll upvote it and delete this one.*

The key bit of intuition is to *run $f$ backwards* - at a glance, it looks like the inverse of $f$ should be a contraction since $f$ is an "anti-contraction," and certainly any fixed point for the inverse of a map is a fixed point for the map itself.

Of course, this assumes that $f$ does in fact have an inverse, which isn't given explicitly. We are told that $f$ is surjective, but we still need to show that $f$ is *injective*.

This, though, is something we can do: supposing $x\not=y$, can you show that we must have $f(x)\not=f(y)$? (HINT: think about $d(x,y)$ ...)